# Firebase OrderByChild return extra empty child

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to make query with orderBy and I get another empty child.

component .ts

```
 loadCourses(){
this.profileProvider.getSpecificCourse().on('value',f=>{
  console.log(f.val());  
})
```

}

provider

```
     getSpecificCourse(){
  return firebase.database().ref(`CoursesRelated`).orderByChild('cs').equalTo(2);  

 }
```

firebase structure
[image]

getting the another empty node
[image]

expected result:
the same result without the empty node.

in addition I want to make another orderby and get the ls equal to 6, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using numeric indexes to store the nodes, which means that Firebase SDK interprets them as an array. For the results: `{ "0": {...}, "2": {...}` it then creates a three element array `[{...}, null, {...}]`.

For a good, longer explanation of how Firebase deals with arrays, read this blog post [Best Practices: Arrays in Firebase](http://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html).

The way to get rid of this behavior is to not use sequential numeric keys. The simplest way to do this is to either add the items by calling Firebase's `push()` method (which generates keys in a format `-K...` and is explained [here](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/02/the-2120-ways-to-ensure-unique_68.html)), or by prefixing the numbers with a fixed string (e.g. `Course0`, `Course1`, `Course2`). Since these format are strings, they bypass the Firebase SDK's array-coercion logic.